# '(_, _, _) -> Void' is not convertible to 'Result<Post> -> Void'

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

In the view controller I have this code:

```
newPost!.save({ (post, error) in
        //Error here. 

        if let anError = error {
            print("error calling POST on /posts")
            print(anError)
            return
        }
        guard let post = post else {
            print("error calling POST on /posts: result is nil")
            return
        }
        // success!
        print(post.description())
        print(post.title)

    })
```

I don't quite understand the `Result<Whatever>` syntax, `Result` should be something from Alamofire 2, `Post` is a class I created, but what does `Result<Post> -> Void` altogether mean and what should I change about it?

Update:

```
func save(completionHandler: (Result<Post>) -> Void) {

let fields: [String: AnyObject]? = self.toJSON()
if fields == nil {

print("Error: error converting newPost fields to JSON")
return

}
```

Comment: What is the signature of the save method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your completion handler definition and the way you have called it are different, try something like this for your completion handler if you want to call it that way:

```
func save(completionHandler: (post:Post?, error:String?) -> Void) {

    let fields: [String: AnyObject]? = self.toJSON()
    if fields == nil {
       completionHandler(nil, "Error converting newPost fields to JSON")
       return
    }
    // rest of code, eventually call completionHandler with success
}
```

For Swift 2:

```
func save(completionHandler: (post:Post?, error:String?) -> Void) {

    guard let fields = self.toJSON() else {
         completionHandler(nil, "Error converting newPost fields to JSON")
         return
    }
    // rest of code, eventually call completionHandler with success

}
```

[Closures Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94)